# position value in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to insert an int value in a vector object at position -1, i.e. :

```
vector<int> v;
int p = 12;
vector<int>::iterator it = -1;
v.insert(it,1,p);
```

is it possible in c++ ? or it must always be positive ?

Comment: What does position -1 mean? To the front? An iterator to the beginning is obtained with `v.begin()`.

Comment: Are you coming from a python background where -1 is the last element?

Comment: no I actually meant -1 like v[-1], but it's ok pb solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insertion using the `insert` method occurs always *before* the specified iterator, so to insert at the first position (i.e. * before* the current first element) use:

```
v.insert(v.begin(), p);
```

(you can omit the `count` parameter, if you only insert a single element).

Insertion at the last position can be done using the `end()` iterator like

```
v.insert(v.end(), p);
```

or, in case of vectors, using `push_back()` like

```
v.push_back(p);
```

For accessing vectors, you can only use non-negative indices, i.e. `v[-1]` is invalid.

Also you cannot assign an integer to an iterator, mainly because the iterator encapsulates both, the position *and* the container it is refering to. If you want to 'construct' an iterator for a specified position, use additions like:

```
std::vector<int> it = v.begin() + index;
```

(Note, that addition to iterators only works for so called *random access iterators*, thus it depends on the container type.)

Comment: indeed your post is very useful :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. `vector`-indices have to be greater or equal to 0. You would have to use a `std::map` if you want negative indices.

Answer (score 1):

Vector indices start from zero. There is therefore no such thing as "position -1".

If you want to insert the element at the start of the vector, use `v.begin()` as the insertion position.

Answer (score 1):

Vectors indicates an index and index can't be a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Always positive. And you do this:

```
v[2] = 5;
```

Only an example. The index can't be negative, because it is a position. Negative positions don't exist.